# Generate Rig error: key "ORG-nose" not found'

Tags: rigging, rigify

In order to generate a bone rig I have created the metarig and adjusted it to my model/character. As I am trying to create something simple (to use it in Unity), I removed the face and ears.

[image: Character with the metarig]

Then I re-calculated the noremal ("Shift + N" and then "Y").

Once I generated the rig (`Object Data Properties > Rigify Buttons > Generate Rig`) I got the following error:

> Generation has thrown an exception: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key
>   "ORG-nose" not found'

And in the Layers it appears a new one named "rig" and it highlights the following:

[image: New Layer - Rig]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the problem.

The face bones were not all removed as I saw one inside the big bone (*spine.006*) when I moved it.

[image: Small bone]

Removing that small isolated bone named *face* solved the problem.

[image: Problem solved]