# rig not working properly error -ORG -nose-

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, rigify, auto-rig-pro

so I have been modeling a character , and I wanted to generate the rig but I got an error saying , Generation has thrown an exception: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "ORG-nose" not found'
I Could not Really Understood much as I m still learning about rigging and stuff any ideas please? [image: bbb]

new blend : [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159556/generate-rig-error-key-org-nose-not-found?rq=1

Comment: There are several issues. 1) for the ORG-nose problem see John Eason's link. 2) the head bone *spline.006* should be as large as the head 3) The normals of the hands are flipped. You need to fix them else automatic weights won't work properly. 4) You have used the palm bones for the fingers. Not good. They should be in the palm area of the hand. 5) The neck bone is detached from the spline. This will give you an error. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199644/107598 -- Tip: use Box Select or Lasso Select to select the tail/head of the bones so that they stay together

Comment: hey blunder sorry for the late reply, so basically it worked thank you for that , appreciate it , but one problem im facing after regenerating the rig , the fingers are not bending like it supposed to , they are kinda glitchy everytime i try to *scale down* the fingers  , i will upload the blend and some screenshots , thanks in advance , thanks john also

Comment: any suggestion.